# How to read a list of values in Pig as a bag and compare it to a specific value?

Tags: apache-pig

**Input:**

ids:

```
1111,2222,3333,4444
```

employee:

```
{"name":"abc","id":"1111"} {"name":"xyz","id":"10"}
{"name":"z","id":"100"} {"name":"m","id":"99"}
{"name":"pqr","id":"3333"}
```

I want to filter employees whose id exists in the given list.

**Expected Output:**

```
{"name":"xyz","id":"10"} {"name":"z","id":"100"}
{"name":"m","id":"99"}
```

Existing Code:

```
idList = LOAD 'pathToFile' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:chararray); 
empl = LOAD 'pathToFile' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad')  AS (data:map[]);
output = FILTER empl BY data#'id' in (idList);
-- not working, states: A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar  
output = FILTER empl BY data#'id' in (idList#id);
-- not working, states: mismatched input 'id' expecting set null
```

Answer (score 0):

`JsonLoad()` is native in `pig > 0.10`, and you can specify the schema:

```sql
empl = LOAD 'pathToFile' USING JsonLoader('name:chararray, id:chararray');
DUMP empl;

(abc,1111)
(xyz,10)
(z,100)
(m,99)
(pqr,3333)
```

You're loading `idList` as a one column table of type `chararray` but you want a list.

Loading it as a one column table (implies modifying you file so there is only one record per line):

```sql
idList = LOAD 'pathToFile' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:chararray);
DUMP idList;   

(1111)
(2222)
(3333)
(4444)
```

or as a one-line file, we'll change the separator so it doesn't split into columns (otherwise it will lead to loading only the first column):

```sql
idList = LOAD 'pathToFile' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (id:chararray);
idList = FOREACH idList GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(id, '[,]')) AS id;
DUMP idList;

(1111)
(2222)
(3333)
(4444)
```

Now we can do a `LEFT JOIN` to see which `id` are not present in `idList` and then a `FILTER` to keep only those. `output` is a reserved keyword, you shouldn't use it:

```sql
res = JOIN empl BY id LEFT, idList BY id;
res = FILTER res BY idList::id IS NULL;
DUMP res;

(xyz,10,)
(m,99,)
(z,100,)
```